# reorder radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

i have a survey that has two radio buttons and when clicked will submit and send to a thank you page and then redirect back to the survey, my question is how do i get the radio buttons to randomize in location but i cant seem to get it to work, is there an issue with my jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>survey</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test7.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   </head>
 <script>
var cc-selector = $("#cc-selector");

cc-selector.html(
    cc-selector.find("label").sort(function(){
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
    })
);
 </script>
    <body>
       <div id="wrapper">
    <header>

     <img src="Win.png" alt="Logo" class="Logo">

     <img src="Screw.jpg" alt="screwLogo" class="screwLogo">



        <h1 class="Survey_Title">Heath and Wellbeing</h1><br>
        <h2 class="Survey_Question">Did you find the most recent Wellbeing campaign useful?</h2><br>

<form action="" method="post">

    <div class="cc-selector">
     <label>
        <input id="happy" type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="happy" onclick="window.location='test6.html';" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy"></label>
        </label>

         <label>
        <input id="sad" type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="sad" onclick="window.location='test6.html';" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc sad"for="sad"></label>
        </label>

    </div>
</form>


        </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: cc-selector is an invalid JS variable name - also you do not load jQuery anywhere

Comment: @mplungjan But it show js errors. Also I edited some text, you could remove snippet, not rollback to break all edits!

Comment: @pedram Your textual changes were not useful and in some cases wrong

Comment: OTHER editors, please do not FIX the code in the question. If you need to fix something please ANSWER the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of randomly moving the `label`s is really nice.
But you entountered these problems:

1. Your main problem was that the variable `cc - selector` wasn't correct. (Variable names can only contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs.)
2. `cc-selector` is a `class`, not an `id`, so you need to select `.cc-selector`, not `#cc-selector`.
3. As there are `label`s in your `label`s, you wanted to target only the direct childs of `cc-selector`. I propose you to use `.children()` instead.
4. You did not include the jQuery library, for example:
   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Note that to randomize the elements order within an array, we need the `.sort(function{…})` returning a number that is randomly `<0`, `0`, `>0`, so `return (Math.random() - 0.5);` covers all our needs.

⋅
⋅
⋅

Here is a working simplified snippet made from your code:
(I removed some of the HTML to have a shorter snippet)

```js
$(".cc-selector").html(
  // $(".cc-selector > label").sort(function() { // What you wanted to do
  $(".cc-selector").children().sort(function() { // What I propose you
    return (Math.random() - 0.5); // No need to use 'round()'
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>(I added texts to see the values. Run the code multiple times to see it moving!)</p>
<div class="cc-selector">
  <label>
    <input id="happy" type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="happy" onclick="window.location='test6.html';" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy">Happy</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input id="sad" type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="sad" onclick="window.location='test6.html';" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc sad"for="sad">Sad</label>
  </label>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Then, you can do the same with more labels:

```js
$(".cc-selector").each(function() {
  $(this).html(
    $(this).children().sort(function() {
      return (Math.random() - 0.5);
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>(Same… with more texts!)</p>
<div class="cc-selector">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="vhappy" />
  <label for="vhappy">Very happy</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="happy" />
  <label for="happy">Happy</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="sad" />
  <label for="sad">Sad</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="vsad" />
  <label for="vsad">Very sad</label>
  </label>
</div>
<p>(… and again!)</p>
<div class="cc-selector">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="vhappy" />
  <label for="vhappy">Very happy</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="happy" />
  <label for="happy">Happy</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="sad" />
  <label for="sad">Sad</label>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="vsad" />
  <label for="vsad">Very sad</label>
  </label>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

So here is what you had wrong in your code:

1. Variable name is not correct ([Source](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)),
2. In your function you want to change html of an element with `id="cc-selector"` but you do not have that element,
3. You have `label` in `label` so jQuery `find()` function will find all labels.

What I did to make it work:

1. Changed variable name,
2. Changed `id="cc-selector"` to `class="cc-selector"`,
3. Changed outer label to div.

**Here is an working example**

```js
var ccselector = $(".cc-selector");

ccselector.html(ccselector.find(".radioHolder").sort(function() {
  return (Math.random() - 0.5);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="cc-selector">
      <div class="radioHolder">
        <input id="happy" type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="happy" onclick="" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy">One</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radioHolder">
        <input id="sad" type="radio" name="radAnswer" value="sad" onclick="" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc sad" for="sad">Two</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```